# Definition lists in Microsoft Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

How can I create definition lists in Microsoft Word 2007?

Something like the following:

**Term A**

A definition goes here

**Term B**

A definition goes here

Comment: Please add more description to your question.

Comment: ... like what? I want to create definition lists. I could not find a built-in tool like there is for bulleted or numbered lists. What is the best way to go about implementing them in a Word 2007 document?

Comment: I have the same question.  Something like, highlight a word and have a "Create Definition" button that when pressed, the word w/ definition is added to a page, sorted alphabetically.  Something like that

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I simulated this behavior by creating two styles: TermStyle and DefinitionStyle. I formatted them as desired, and then set the "following style" option for TermStyle to DefinitionStyle, and vice versa. This lets me enter alternating terms and definitions without needing to do any manual formatting.